# Visual Studio cannot find the PersistKeysToRedis method of Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-protection

Visual Studio claims it cannot find the PersistKeysToRedis method described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.redisdataprotectionbuilderextensions.persistkeystoredis?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I am using dotnet core 2.1.302.  I have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All NuGet package installed, which as far as I can tell is all I need.  I have most of the other methods described in that namespace as the following image shows:

[image: PersistKeysToRedis missing]

I have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection namespace in my using statements.

So why do I not see this method?  It's late on a Friday so maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your link says `PersistKeysToRedis` is in assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis`. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` does not have a reference to this assembly so you need to add it manually.

Comment: You are correct.  I needed to add this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis/

Comment: Note this package is now https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved in my .net Core 3.1 app by installing nuget package,

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis (3.1)